# Set application theme in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way I can set the application theme from inside my application's own code?

For example, a function like that:

```
setApplicationTheme("Plastique");
```

Comment: Surely because the qconfig application changes this. I would take a look into its code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
QStyle * QApplication::setStyle ( const QString & style );
```

Take a look at the Qt docs:

[Qt 5](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qapplication.html#setStyle-1)

[Qt 4.8](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#setStyle-2)

Comment: List of styles on linux build of Qt 4.8: `"Windows", "Motif", "CDE", "Plastique", "GTK+", "Cleanlooks"`