# QT ComboBox dropdown position moving on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt

On Linux: When I select first item from the ComboBox dropdown, it opens downward, but if I select any other item and then open dropdown again, then it doesn't expand downward exactly, some entries are upward and some downward, because of native theme of Linux, but I want them to expand like Windows, all entries just below Text Edit of ComboBox.

I tried implementing like this to move the positon of dropdown and fix it:
`QWidget *popup=combo_box->findChild<QFrame *>(); popup->move(popup->x(),combo_box->rect().bottomLeft().x());`

Can someone tell me the correct logic to make the drop down start just below the text edit field of that ComboBox?

I am new to QT, please forgive the mistakes.
Thank you :)

Comment: Possible solution: [Set application theme in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078950/set-application-theme-in-qt), using  `Windows` theme. However, I do not understand why you want to change this behaviour as it will be familiar to your Linux users.

Comment: @m7913d It is not looking good and since my application is cross platform, its behaviour is supposed to be same across all OS.

Comment: Specifying the theme may be a solution to you. However, I do not agree that a cross platform application should look perfectly identical on all platforms. Windows/mac/linux users are familiar with a slightly different GUI. Why do you think that Qt tries to provide a native look on all platforms, instead of creating an own and identical look on all platforms.

Comment: @m7913d I agree with you, but the combobox is expanding in abrupt manner, after expansion, it is going out of the designated window, hence not looking good.Your idea of setting theme works, but in our application, we are using a customized theme,so theme changes to windows will revert all those changes. I am looking to achieve it without affecting any other thing.